# Choice of LSTM for price prediction

Tags: long-short-term-memory

I have a dataset with features (f) for different stocks (S) and want to infer for price using an LSTM model. Here is my df:

| year | S1_price | S1_f1 | S1_f2 | S2_price | S2_f1 | S2_f2 | Sn_price | Sn_f1 | Sn_f2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2010 | 100 | 0.1 | 0.12 | 200 | 0.2 | 0.22 | 300 | 0.3 | 0.32 |
| 2011 | 105 | 0.4 | 0.42 | 205 | 0.5 | 0.52 | 305 | 0.6 | 0.62 |
| 2012 | 110 | 0.7 | 0.72 | 210 | 0.8 | 0.82 | 310 | 0.9 | 0.92 |
| n |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |

and so on... (example values).

I would like to predict the prices of every stock by using the features as inputs looking 1yr back into the past.

Example for Stock 1 (predict 2012):

```
[[0.1 0.12]
 [0.4 0.42]] 110
```

However, I want to to that for all stocks, so I am not sure which type of LSTM to use.

Your help would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I tend to like GRU and its variants for this type of problem. Although, if your dataset isn't too large you can test some toy models(smaller versions) of the different types to know which will achieve the best accuracy.

Typically a good size to start with in that case would be about 20-25% of your full model size.